# getting back deleted files with git

Tags: git

If I create a new branch and then delete files, can I get them back by checking out a previous commit?

for example:

`git checkout -b get-rid-of-useless-files`

`rm useless.js`

Oh no!

`git checkout`

phew(?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to manojids answer, if you already `git rm /path/to/deleted/file` you can still `git reset HEAD /path/to/deleted/file` and then `git checkout -- /path/to/deleted/file`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if a file is already checked in and you delete it, you can get it back:

```
git checkout -- path/to/deleted/file
```